# Can i add dummy variables before testing the residuals for normality?

Tags: normal-distribution, residuals, normality-assumption, quantile-regression, eviews

I am using eviews 13 and I want to run these equations

```
Co c yd yd(-1) 
Co c yd co(-1)
```

With quantile regression I want to test the residuals for normality and conclude that since it's not normal I should use quantile regression.

My models have structural breaks which I intend to fix with time based dummy variables.

Should I add dummies to my model before testing the residual for normality or after?

Comment: Please use complete sentences and do not use sentence fragments. Quite possibly, English is not your first language. That's fine if so, but either way (1) the personal pronoun I is correctly written as upper case and (2) writing it otherwise is in practice divisive.

Answer (score 0):

- When you are testing the assumptions of the model, you need to test the assumptions for the model you are referring to. So if you would test the assumptions for some model and then modify it (e.g. add additional features), it would tell you nothing about the new model.
- Quantile regression does not make an assumption that the residuals are normally distributed.